# Return different value types from an object, depending on the type cast

Tags: java, casting, functional-interface

I've seen methods that return a different value types from an object depending on the type cast, similar to this:

`(String) Object.get() //returns a string`

`(Integer) Object.get() //returns an int`

etc.

I’m trying to replicate this behavior (for learning purposes) by creating an Employee class like this:

```
public class Employee {
    String name;
    int age;

    public Employee (String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Now, let's assume I create a new Employee object:

`Employee tomJones = new Employee("Tom Jones", 38);`

Is it possible to somehow do this (see below)?

`(String) tomJones.get() //returns “Tom Jones”`

`(Integer) tomjones.get() //returns 38`

I'm trying to replicate some behavior that I've previously seen in code and not having all the problem's details makes it quite hard for me as a beginner to come up with something. So, I tried using different interfaces and some lambdas, but only managed to make a mess, with no result.

Comment: No, it is not possible. Please add the code you've previously seen to your question.

Comment: no, use getName() and getAge().

Comment: I think you got a bit confused about what you saw originally. It's not getting something based on the type cast. It's just that the programmer happens to know the current object there is Integer, and so casts to Integer. For example, when reading from a database that has an Integer column and a String column, you need to know which column you are reading to use this.

Comment: This^ though I m confused because even JDBC ResultSet doesnt use get() for both int and string but they have getInt(), getString() etc. Do you think you might have misremembered something OP?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible and if you are trying to overload the method then the number of parameters in two methods should be different or the data types of the parameters or the Order of the parameters.